# After changing the query params in URL the page is remounting again

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some filters on the page and after been applied I want to store those filter values in URL with query params. But whenever I change the param it remounts the page again and causes `componentDidMount` to call again. I wanted to be notified by `getDerivedStateFromProps:static` whenever props change.

This function I use to update my query params. Sample URL https://qa.portal.tech/feeds?country=USA&page=1&pageSize=10&price=yes

```
export const updateQueryString = (history: History, queryParams: any) => {
  const {
    replace,
    location: { pathname }
  } = history;

  replace({
    pathname,
    search: queryString.stringify({
      ...queryParams
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: You can use history.push to update instead of replace

Comment: I have tried that as well but remounting happing

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of react-router-dom from v5, the behaviour has changed. Even on param or query update the component is remounted instead of rerendered when you change the url directly.

However using link actually follows the re-render pattern

Here is [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-url-parameters-zw741?file=/example.js) demonstrating the change